# Skip "Sign in to Google" when setting up new Android device

Tags: privacy, accounts, nvidia-shield

I recently got a new Nvidia Shield TV. On the first start, after asked me to set up my language and connect to my wifi, it prompts me to "Sign in to Google." The only options on the screen are "use your phone or laptop" and "use your password." How can I bypass this step?

Comment: You can not. They call it android, but in fact it's alphabet.

Comment: Basically, what are you going to gain out of bypassing this step? i mean if you dont want to give your google account details, just create another one...it dosent cost one cent to create one. Hopefully, your issue will be addressed after this

Comment: It's more like Google doesn't need to know more about me. But this isn't just a Google thing; most modern OSes (Mac OS, iOS, Windows) push you to sign in.

Answer (score 3):

My Shield TV worked just fine for three years without a Google account, but the Oreo update appeared to lock me into a signup page; This is pretty obnoxious.

You can double-tap the home button and dismiss all the active applications; once you do that the launcher will come up without requiring you to login to a Google account or give them your phone number to create one.

You will have a permanent notification suggesting you sign in, though.